# Spring Integration Java DSL - IntegrationFlow multiple subscribers

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am getting up too speed with Spring Integration DSL. I am playing with the below example.

```
 @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow flow() {
        return IntegrationFlows.from(INBOX)
                .transform(p -> "world")
                .get();
    }
```

I am looking for the ability from this one flow to subscribe to multiple channels. I cannot find anything about this.

For example something like the below, where this flow is subscribed to different channels.

```
 @Bean
        public IntegrationFlow flow() {
            return IntegrationFlows.from(INBOX).flow(INBOX2)
                    .transform(p -> "world")
                    .get();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That isn't possible. There is just no any `Endpoint` with several `inputChannel`s.

On the other hand we don't need such a complexity since we always can `bridge` from one channel to another:

```
@Bean
@BridgeTo(INBOX)
public MessageChannel INBOX2() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}
```

Also you can consider to use some `router` to always evaluate to the desired channel for output.

The `MessageChannel` is complex per se in the Spring Integration design, that it won't sound good to mess the endpoint logic.

Answer (score 1):

In this tutorial[[Receive and send multiple JMS messages in one transaction with Spring Integration Java DSL]](https://axxes.com/java/receive-and-send-multiple-jms-messages-in-one-transaction-with-spring-integration-java-dsl/), they have described like that

> however this property is not yet available to the Java DSL. Another
>   way to solve this problem would be to replace the message driven
>   channel adapter with a transactional poller, this however is also not
>   possible in the current Java DSL. To fix this we replaced the
>   jmsFactory in the outbound adapter with a jmsTemplate with the session
>   transacted set to true. Resulting in:
>
> ```
> IntegrationFlows
>   .from(subscribableChannel())
>   .handle(Jms.outboundAdapter(jmsTemplate).destination(QUEUE2))
> .get();
> ```